# In Google Sheets, is there a way to conditionally substitute the output of an IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Within Google Sheets, I'm trying to create an array which does the following:

- Import a specific column, containing tickboxes, from multiple sheets owned by different individuals
- If the tickbox is set to TRUE, the IMPORTRANGE output should display the name of the respective individual and not "TRUE".

So if Joe ticked a box in his sheet, the IMPORTRANGE output would say "Joe".

I have attempted the following which did not work for me:

```
={IF(IMPORTRANGE(IDs!$B$4,"E2:E")=TRUE,"Joe"," ");IF(IMPORTRANGE(IDs!$B$5)=TRUE,"Sam"," ")}
```

I'm assuming this doesn't work because the IF overriding the IMPORTRANGE will not actually produce a range. Instead, if TRUE is present within the IMPORTRANGE, it only includes the individual name in the first row.

Is there a formula that would let me substitute the TRUE output with the respective individual name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the range in your second `IMPORTRANGE`:

```
={ IF(IMPORTRANGE(IDs!$B$4,"E2:E")=TRUE,"Joe","");
   IF(IMPORTRANGE(IDs!$B$5)=TRUE,"Sam"," ")}
```

should include the range for Sam's sheet:

```
={ IF(IMPORTRANGE(IDs!$B$4,"E2:E")=TRUE,"Joe","");
   IF(IMPORTRANGE(IDs!$B$5,"E2:E")=TRUE,"Sam"," ")} << This has been changed
```

After adding a second range, this worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for pointing that out. That was an error on my part with regards to inputting the question. If Joe and Sam have several rows with tickboxes where selected, and I import the combined ranges, how can I have those TRUEs set as the individual's name?